# Upgrade website from ASP.Net 3.5 to 3.5 sp1

Tags: .net, asp.net-3.5, upgrade, .net-3.5

Is there anything special that needs to happen to a 3.5 web.config file to take advantage of new features in sp1?

Comment: The existing site is 3.5.  I updated the subject to better state this.

Answer (score 2):

No! All you need to do is change build framework version to 3.5 and start using 3.5 features in your application. This applies to all types of .Net projects (including web application or website project).

Comment: I'm already using 3.5, I am wondering if there are any changes to go to 3.5 sp1.

Comment: Oh Ok, in that case  you do not need to do anything specific to upgrade to SP1 (other than installing SP).